# How get a substring in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, ruby-on-rails-4, substring

I have a string and need to extract the device_id. In the example I would need "00:06:66:7C:6A:C0"

```
{   "app_data_quota":{"max":153600,"used":9432},
    "aux_device_data_reference":{"reference_id":70},
    "aux_device_data_in":{"device_id":"00:06:66:7C:6A:C0","aux_data":"LS0tCiQkJA=="},
    "aux_device_data_quota":{"max":153600,"used":9432}
}
```

Comment: `h.values.select{ |x| x[:device_id] }[0][:device_id]` ?

Comment: Thanks @kiddorails, do you first convert into a Hash? How would you convert this string into a Hash?

Comment: `h = eval(string)`

Answer (score 1):

Lut.

You can save your data in a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) and then extract the 'device_id' doing something like this:

```
device_data = {   "app_data_quota":{"max":153600,"used":9432},
    "aux_device_data_reference":{"reference_id":70},
    "aux_device_data_in":{"device_id":"00:06:66:7C:6A:C0","aux_data":"LS0tCiQkJA=="},
    "aux_device_data_quota":{"max":153600,"used":9432}
}
device_id = device_data[:aux_device_data_in][:device_id]
```

Regards

Comment: Hi Carlos, how can you convert this string into a Hash? I dont find a straightforward solution.

Comment: `device_data = eval(your_string)`